# What type of speakers and speaker cable should I use to connect to my Behringer U-Phoria UMC202HD audio interface outputs?

Tags: recording, speakers

I've just started out with setting up recording equipment, so I'm a newbie with this type of configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Generally, you're going to need some kind of studio monitors. Try looking around on Amazon for that.

Answer (score 3):

The Behringer U-Phoria UMC202HD has **2 x 1⁄4 inch TRS** output sockets(L/R).

You need **monitors** for a start. Studio monitors are basically speakers with a refined, flat response i.e. a clean sound.

Studio monitors are usually self-powered, so you wouldn't need an amp. Self-powered monitors are called 'active' monitors as opposed to 'passive' monitors.

There is a huge range of studio monitors from budget to over-the-top expensive on the internet. They will usually have **XLR or TRS input sockets**, sometimes both.

You will need a lead with a **1/4 inch TRS jack** on one end and *[whatever input connection your monitors have]* on the other end.

There are other questions on this site that may interest you. Check the list to the right->.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what would happen if you connected a passive speaker? Would their typical 4-8 Ohm impedance short/overload the output preamp? (I guess obviously it's protected against that, but will it disengage?)